# Is it possible to connect multiple GND with one wire?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am making the circuit using Stage and Controller, Power Supply and DAC Card.
As for the system, the power supply provides a 15 V voltage to the controller/amplifier, and a 0 to 10 V control voltage through the DAC. This causes the controller/amplifier to amplify the voltage coming through Control In by 10 times and put it into Stage, and the stage will move depending on the voltage taken.

Finally, not all of them are shown in the figure, but there are four or five lines that need to be connected to the GND from the controller/Amplifier (test GND, Protective GND, for monitoring the voltage on the stage, etc.), all of which are connected to one wire by soldering as shown in the picture.

The wires were all connected by referring to the manual using wires, soldering, and banana jacks.

But It doesn't work, so I'm asking you this question.

Here's what I'm curious about.

1. Can I connect various GND lines at once as shown in the picture?
   Now, there are about five lines that need to be connected to the GND that are connected together.
   Will that connect well?
2. There are two current GND sources. One GND connected to DAC through BNC Cable, and GND terminal present at Power Supply terminal. if there are two GNDs, does GND be properly captured?

Thank you for reading it.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Yes you can. How does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon how "zero volts" your grounds must be.

Notice I wrote ground(s)

Make a list of grounds, and write down the trash levels you need.

Then identify the DC currents flowing, and compute the I*R. Compare this to your list.

And identify the power supply trash currents, and compute the

V = L * dI/dT

using estimated inductance of 1,000 nanoHenries per 1,000 milliMeters.

You can reduce the power supply trash currents, producing very small dI/dT, with small series resistors and large capacitors.

I call these "local batteries" because the DC comes from your power supply,  but the transients now come from the large **LOCAL** capacitor.

The series resistor is essential to isolation, and for dampening.

1 ohm and 1,000uf are good values. Notice this is a 160 Hz low pass filter.
Mind the DC drops.

Where you ground the capacitor ----- is critical.

============= edit ============

using a **STAR** ground will help, if the star is the lowest impedance point --- that means the star must be at the battery, or the gnd output of your power supply

Using MOSFET GATE DRIVERS may help to separate sensitive regions from fast-switching regions; the input will be logic levels; the output can be 5/12/18 volts as needed to control your high current motor-driver FETS. Have 0.1uf right across the gate driver, so the fast gate-charging currents come from that cap. And maybe 1 ohm or 10 ohm in the VDD to the gate-driver, to localize the surges.

Basically you need to make sketches and visualize where the fast current surges flow. Using remote gate-drivers is  one way to move fast edges away from your MCU.